# Review icon persists, when I have nothing to review?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

For the last several hours, the little orange edit circle on SA:

[image]

has remained at the top of my screen, indicating one review pending, but when I click it, the screen says "There are no items for you to review."

While possibly a coincidence, today for the first time, I suggested an edit to a wiki page, which I do not yet have sufficient privilege to unilaterally change.

Comment: Yup, that's what's in the review queue. Sounds like a bug to me! (P.S. I didn't realize that tag wiki was so thorough - that's the kind of thing that really belongs as the answer to a canonical question, not hidden away as a tag wiki. I'll try and sort that out at some point.)

Comment: I've seen this on a different stack. [See here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/426/moderator-tools-asking-me-to-take-action-i-cant-take)

Answer (score 2):

The number correctly indicated the number of active review tasks, though not the number of tasks that you, personally, were eligible to review.

Checking each of them ahead of time to see if you're eligible to review them would be a lot of extra overhead, and the number could still be wrong in some cases.